# How to subtract seconds from a datetime and compare it?

Tags: python, datetime, time, subtraction, seconds

So I did see all the topics here about subtracting seconds from `datetime`s and subtracting `datetime`s in general, but I'm still stuck and trying to solve it for a long time.

I wrote the following codes.

This part of the codes sends a timestamp to a my txt file, in the `ttl` parameter.

```
lines.append(""+dataFather.decode()[:-1]+','+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))
```

It sends it as a string.

Then, I just keep this inside the time varaible.

```
    infoList = line.split(",")
.....
            time = infoList[3]
```

Then, in an other run of the code, I just want to check whether the subtract between the seconds is bigger or smaller than 60.

```
timeDif = datetime.now()-datetime.strptime(time, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
if 60 > timeDif.seconds():
     ......
```

But I got the following error, it doesn't even reach the "if" statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server_copy.py", line 36, in <module>
    timeDif = datetime.now()- datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

and it's weird because I did use:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

Where is the error here?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you show

```
timeDif = datetime.now()-datetime.strptime(time, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

but in the error it's clearly

```
timeDif = datetime.now()- datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

So your example and error message use different code. Show us the entire file where you run this.

Also why previously you were using `datetime.datetime`?

```
lines.append(""+dataFather.decode()[:-1]+','+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Try to be consistent and it will resolve itself.

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that and read about importing datetime and fixed the issues. But now I have some other error  because I'm trying to subtract "datetime.now()" which forammted in other way than "datetime.strptime" and then it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

dont use `timeDif.seconds()` seconds is not a method

try to use `timeDif.seconds` and it will work just fine!

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep

before = datetime.now()
sleep(5) # wait for 5 se
now = datetime.now()

timeDif = now-before

print(str(timeDif.seconds))
```

Comment: As I said it doesn't even reach the "if" statement.